# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Martial Arts Stack Exchange](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What is Qi power and has it been proven to exist scientifically?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/what-is-qi-power-and-has-it-been-proven-to-exist-scientifically)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [When was the Southern Shaolin Temple destroyed?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/when-was-the-southern-shaolin-temple-destroyed)

  **Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [Junior BJJ belts transformation when one becomes adult](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2020/junior-bjj-belts-transformation-when-one-becomes-adult)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [How to build up endurance when rolling?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2021/how-to-build-up-endurance-when-rolling)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What exercises help with explosive hip rotation](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-exercises-help-with-explosive-hip-rotation)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Sparring against Offensive Fighters](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2084/sparring-against-offensive-fighters)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What is Jason Bourne's fighting style called](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2034/what-is-jason-bournes-fighting-style-called)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [What martial art should I try if I want to train with a wide variety of weapons?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2056/what-martial-art-should-i-try-if-i-want-to-train-with-a-wide-variety-of-weapons)

  **Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [What are the common techniques to close the gap in jeet kune do?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2068/what-are-the-common-techniques-to-close-the-gap-in-jeet-kune-do)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What choke holds or submissions are safe enough for a beginner to practice?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2027/what-choke-holds-or-submissions-are-safe-enough-for-a-beginner-to-practice)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

Comment: I'd be interested to hear from the 4 "Needs Improvements" on "What is Qi power?"

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to hear from the 4 "Needs Improvements" on "What is Qi power?" as well as the 3 on the last question, "What choke holds are safe for a beginner?" More answers are almost always good, but I thought those two had a good selection of views and were pretty fair.

I do think that this random sampling showed off a deep need for better questions. A lot of these are not questions that people are actually facing.